# Protractor Not able to identify element within iframe

Tags: javascript, typescript, protractor

I am trying to go into a iframe and then locate a Text element. I am not able to get the same. I tried

```
await browser.driver.switchTo().frame(this.intercomFrame);
console.log(element(by.xpath("//div[@class='intercom-messenger-header']/h1")).getText());
```

Failing to get to h1 as it doesn't look like the iframe  switching works.

Can someone advise. Also is there some promises I can use.

Comment: attach your error stack

Comment: @SergeyPleshakov This is code base